# Stuck at "Updates and other software" whlie trying to install Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, 18.04, updates

I've been trying to install Ubuntu 18.04 from a USB drive (as a dual boot with Windows 10), and the installer gets stuck at the "Updates and other software" step. I thought it was only a matter of patience, but after waiting an hour and a half, nothing happened. I already tried the steps specified in [this bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1766978), but nothing worked.

According to the bug report I linked above, it's because there's a dedicated Windows partition on the main disk. I already made another partition (with a capacity of 150 GB), but it didn't fix the issue.

I'd really appreciate any kind of help. I really have no idea of how to fix this.

Comment: Doing a dual boot. Sorry for not mentioning it in the OP.

Comment: Yep, I am. Alright, I'll try to do the installation once again, but this time without connecting to the internet. I'll let you know how it goes. Thanks!

Comment: Update: unfortunately, I'm still stuck at "Updates and other software", despite not connecting to any network.

Comment: Alright, I'm still unable to install Ubuntu, but now I know where the issue may lie. After trying other distros based on Ubuntu (Mint and KDE Neon) and facing the exact same problema, I decided to try to install Debian. Debian's installer let me know that it specifically failed on the "Detect disks" step. It makes sense, since in Ubuntu's installer, the step right after "Updates and other software" is related to disks and disks partitions. I'll try to see what I can do regarding that.

Comment: Just a note that I've been trying to install Ubuntu and found that while it appears to have frozen, if I wait around 10 minutes it actually succeeds.  The next step after this screen is to partition the disk and it seems that the OS prober is running really slow.  No idea why, but it does get there in the end.  So if this happens to you, maybe get to that screen, click continue and then go make a coffee.